# Different ways on calling array data types to print?

Tags: c, arrays, reference

So, I got this for my computer exam (C gcc-4.9.2):
Will the following statements give the same output? Assume a is an array.

a) `printf("%d", a + 1);`

b) `printf("%d", &a + 1);`

c) `printf("%d", a[0] + 1);`

Comment: `b)` and  `c)` are undefined behavior. `&T` is guaranteed to be a pointer type, and `"%d"` `printf()`-specifier is defined to print an `int`. After your edits, only `c)` is defined behavior (assuming `a` is an array if `int`), `a)` and `b)` are undefined.

Comment: @EOF What about the a) part?

Comment: `a[1]`, UB, `a[0]+1`, so no.

Comment: @EOF `c)` is well defined, if `a` is an array of at least one `int`. The other are only undefined behavior because the format is wrong.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: The question was edited, and thus I also edited my comment.

Comment: Sorry about the c) part, I just edited it.

Comment: Actually all can be UB. See [ask] and provide a [mcve]!

Comment: It is a simple thing to try and check for self,

Comment: @SundeepBorra: "Try and check" doesn't work for undefined behavior. The compiler is under no obligation to be consistent for this.

Comment: It is a simple thing to try and check for self,
The thing is that it is unclear if the array is single array or double array, and even then, No two options will yield the same answer, in your query.

It(array access) works as below: if it is a[10]; then
&a[0], a+0, &a+0 will point to same pointer/address.

and if double array, of a[10][10]; then too
&a[0], a+0, &a+0 will point to same pointer/address.
a, a+0, a+0+0, &a[0], &a[0][0] will point to same pointer/address.

NOTE: All are supposed to be pointers, which means the format specifier should be %p for pointers, and %d for integers

Answer (score 1):

> Will the following statements give the same output?

Short answer: No.

Details below:

Assuming `a` to be defined as

```
int a[N];
```

with

```
N >= 1
```

**and** at least the 1st element of `a` had been initialised properly (case 3. depends on this latter perquisite).

1. `printf("%d", a + 1);`

   ```
   a + 1
   ```

   evaluates to a pointer with the value

   ```
   ((char*) &a[0]) + 1 * sizeof a[0]
   ```

   Printing it using `%d` invokes UB. Anything could happen/be printed. Use `%p` to print `void`-pointer's value. Cast the pointer passed using `(void*)`.
2. `printf("%d", &a + 1);`

   ```
   &a + 1
   ```

   evaluates to a pointer with the value

   ```
   ((char*) &a) + 1 * sizeof a
   ```

   (The latter value is different from the result of 1. if `N > 1`.)

   Printing it using `%d` invokes UB. Anything could happen/be printed. Use `%p` to print `void`-pointer's value. Cast the pointer passed using `(void*)`.
3. `printf("%d", a[0] + 1);`

   Some integer value + 1 as per the array's 1st element's initialisation will be printed.

Comment: Your pointer arithmetic doesn't work like that unless you cast to `[signed/unsigned/ ]char *`.

Comment: @EOF: Thanks. Explaining pointer arithmetics in C using C code is somehow a recursive problem ... :-S

Comment: I'd cite a bit of the C11 standard, but nobody seems to appreciate that...

Answer (score -1):

a) `printf("%d", a + 1);` takes the address of the array `a`. Adding 1 to it means the pointer now points to the second element (i.e. the pointer is incremented with `sizeof(int)` bytes). Printing an address as a number is not defined. To print an address, use `printf("%p", a);`.

b) `printf("%d", &a + 1);` In `&a` the type is 'pointer to array of int' and adding 1 will add the size of the *whole array*, not of an int. So the address of the first element beyond the array will be provided to printf (see above for printing addresses).

c) `printf("%d", a[0] + 1);` will print the value of the first element of `a`, plus 1.

> C11 draft standard n1570: 6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators 3  *Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator, the _Alignof operator, or the unary & operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an expression that has type ‘‘array of type’’ is converted to an expression with type ‘‘pointer to type’’[...]*

Thanks to user EOF who pointed out some errors in earlier versions of this answer.

Comment: `a)` is undefined for the same reason `b)` is.

Comment: I didn't quite get the logic for the a) part. Why would it add '1' to the 'address' instead of the actual value?

Comment: @Stephanie: Paul is wrong about `a)` being defined. `printf("%d", *(a+1));` would to what Paul suggests.

Comment: @EOF Without the pointer, it seems to be undefined..am I on the right track?

Comment: @Stephanie: C11 draft standard n1570: `6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators 3 Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator, the _Alignof operator, or the unary & operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an expression that has type ‘‘array of type’’ is converted to an expression with type ‘‘pointer to type’’[...]` so your `int[]` is treated a an `int*` in `a)` and `c)`. `a + 1` is *also* an `int*`, but `*(a+1)` is an `int`, provided `sizeof(a) > sizeof(int)`.

Comment: @Stephanie passing an `int*` (or `int(*)[]`, as in `b)`) to `printf("%d")` is undefined behavior.

Comment: Also, the  `&` in `b)` is **not ignored**. The type of `&a` is `pointer to array of int`, rather than `pointer to int`. I'm a bit surprised I have to point out so many errors in an answer by a 5k+ user.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie `&a` is an `int(*)[n]`, where the size of the array (`n`) is pretty important: `(&a)[1]` will point *past the array*, not to the second `int` in the array.

Comment: @EOF, aren't "pointer to int" and "pointer to array of int" equivalent? `a+1` points to the second element of `a[]`. `int *i=malloc(10*sizeof(int))` allows to write `i++` to point to the next element. Arrays and pointers are equivalent in C. Taking the address of an address is ignored.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Have you *read* my comment? Have you *tried this out*? Why do I have to educate a 5k+ user? While you can do `i++`, you *certainly* can't do `a++`, which should already tell you that **arrays are not pointers**.

Comment: @EOF, my apologies and thanks. Seems I am not so strong in type semantics. I updated my answer.

Comment: While I'm glad we found agreement, the answer is a bit of a mess now. I'd recommend rewriting it so others can learn from it.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie You should probably point out that `printf("%d", pointer)` is undefined, and you could post the correct way, `printf("%p", (void*)pointer)`. Also, I'd recommend putting the C11 standard citation I gave earlier into the answer, and referring to it to clarify some of the explanations you've made.

Comment: The whole "address of address is meaningless" problem goes away if you stop believing that an array is a pointer. It is not. An array is an object, with the curious property of turning into a pointer in some circumstances that don't include taking the address.

Answer (score -2):

Note: The name of array variable gives its starting address.

```
printf("%d", a + 1);
```

So a equals `&a[0]`. So the above statement is equal to `&a[0]+sizeof(a)*1` which equals `&a[1]`. That is address of `a[1]`.

```
printf("%d", &a + 1);
```

This can be approximated to address of address of `a[0] + 1` which will be some gibberish.

```
printf("%d", a[0] + 1);
```

This is value of `a[0]+1`.

Comment: Omkar, please see the errors I made in my answer about b).

Comment: "*which will be some gibberish.*" no, it most likely is well defined.